# How to use list control from function in mfc c++

Tags: mfc, listcontrol

I have function

```
void go() {
listcontrol1.InsertColumn(1, _T("Code"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 150);
}
```

then i want to access it with button

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedButton3()
{
go();
}
```

I have added variable listcontrol1 to IDC_LIST1 but it shows that listcontrol1 is unidentified. Everything works fine except when i call it from function go ()
I tried to declare it many ways but doesn't work.
Any idea ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the Visual Studio wizard to add a control, it creates it as a member of a class. In your case it's probably part of `CMFCApplicationDlg` but you can check the properties of the control to be sure. That means that either `go` should be a member function as well, or you can pass a pointer or reference to `CMFCApplicationDlg` as a parameter into the function.

```
void go(CMFCApplicationDlg * pdlg) {
    pdlg->listcontrol1.InsertColumn(1, _T("Code"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 150);
}
```

Comment: When compiling i get this error: Error C2660: 'go' : function does not take 0 arguments. Any  idea ?

Comment: @Clax you also need to change the spot where you're *calling* `go`. The error message is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: i tried to put between ( ) when calling go() but still get errors

Comment: your code resolved the first problem but i'm trying to solve this now and can't find any answer anywhere on google related to this. just send me the complete answer. thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried go(this) and it works. is this correct way to do it ?

Comment: @Clax yes that's exactly what I expected you to do.